# EvoPdf Could not create the Document. The method parameter cannot be null

Tags: c#, evopdf

I have problem with **EvoPdf**. Look at the line below:

```
EvoPdf.Document pdfDocument = new EvoPdf.Document(docFile);
```

Where `docFile` is valid path to file. I had checked it twice.
And the exception message is:

```
Could not create the Document. The method parameter cannot be null
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is docFile a valid pdf file? You can validate it here: https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx.

Comment: There could also be a hint if you look in the stacktrace of the exception.